# Mobile Website report downloads for later analysis

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm working on developing an embedded system that has WiFi connectivity for checking status. So the on board system is hosting a web server and I can connect to its WiFi network. I can see the webpages. But I would like to have the website provide a download of logged data. What are my options that work across a wide range of mobile devices. Obviously Android and iOS, but since I'm a Windows Phone user I'd like that as well.

For the embedded system it is running Lighttpd and we are utilizing jquery and jquery-mobile. I've thought about generating PDFs on the server, but not all phones have PDF readers installed. So I'm wondering has anyone else ran across this type of situation of needing to generate reports, save them to a phone, and then copy them to a computer later.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at jIO ([website](http://www.j-io.org/)/[github](https://github.com/nexedi/jio)), which would allow you to store and auto-sync JSON documents across multiple storages.

So your users could pull JSON from your webDav, xWiki, S3 or any storage ("any" would require you to write your own jIO connector).

Documents would be stored in users `localStorage`. jIO also provides a `complexQueries` module, which allows you to query documents stored, so you would have a syncing, lightweight, javascript-only "database" mockup.

PDF could be generated on the client aswell (e.g. using [jspdf](http://www.j-io.org/)), but keeping files in JSON should make them more portable into different formats (like an HTML page displaying JSON data on the client).

**EDIT:**
I don't exactly know what your requirements are, but from what I understand I would setup a [replicate revison storage](http://www.j-io.org/documentation) and in the `storage_list` I would add localstorage and my "remote data storage" (say webDav), where I keep my downloadable data.

So when initializing your app you would do something like this:

```
    var myReaderStorage = JIO.newJio({
        "type": "replicaterevision",
        "storage_list": [
            {
            "type": "revision",
            "sub_storage": 
                {
                // this will your users local storage
                "type": "local",
                "username": <string>,
                "application_name": <string>
                 }
            }, 
            {
            "type": "revision",
            "sub_storage": {
                "type": "dav",
                "username": <string>,
                "password": <string>,
                "url": <string>
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

This will "connect" your users localstorage with your webDav storage and also setup a revisioning system. So for example:

1. User downloads app = new JIO will be initialized.
2. If you `GET` a document, the system will try to pull from localstorage (if there) or remote storage.
3. Once found, all storages will be synced, so `file-A_version1` will be made available on both local and webdav
4. The user can now edit the file (if you allow), creating `file-A_version2`
5. Calling `PUT` will save to localstorage and webDav
6. User calls app from desktop = initialize application again
7. `GET` will try to pull from localStorage (still empty) or remote.
8. `file-A_version2` will be loaded from webDav and will be stored in localStorage aswell

This is just a rough setup but you should get the idea. You could continue like this:

1. Smartphone is offline. User changes file on desktop creating `file-A_version3`
2. `file-A_version3` is sync-ed with webDav
3. Next time user access app via smartphone, system detects conflict (`file-A_version1` on smartphone, `file-A_version3` on webDav). Both versions will be available on the smartphone and you can write your own logic which one to remove using `REMOVE`

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This seems interesting, and I'd have to look at it some more. But storing it on the phones localStorage seems reasonable. The problem is how to get the document off of the phone and then onto the person's desktop. Could we make a reader website that can access that information?

Comment: So I'm not sure, if this is what I need. I have a none web connected embedded system hosting a site. I want to pull the reports out of there on my phone. So using jIO I was able to store information on my browser's local storage using the examples on the jIO website. However, I would need some way of accessing that storage on another website. Is this functionality that jIO supports?

Comment: what do you mean by "another website"? When you setup a `replicate storage` with both local and webDav and `jio.POST`, your file will be stored on localstorage AND webDav. From webDav it would be accessible "from another website", where you would also setup a jiO (only webDav for example) and then `jio.GET`.

Comment: if you are not familiar with webDav, you can try the `S3` storage, which is up on git since yesterday.

Comment: I don't know, maybe we are talking past each other. The website that is generating the reports doesn't have an internet connection. It only has local connections to the phones. So the report doesn't exist online. It exists only on the equipment, and the phone (in the setup we are trying to use). As I said, I can save information to the phone from the equipment from jIO, but my problem is how to read it from the phone on another website where the information can be stored.

Comment: ah, sorry. If you don't have an internet connection, I'm afraid I can't help. And I guess you will have a hard time finding any technique or plugin to get your data from the phone to destination xyz.